# Saving values in Android settings

Tags: java, android

Im saving a Ringtone with this code in Android settings:

```
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(outPath);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

this code saves in:

```
    content://media/INTERNAL/audio/media/[FILE NAME]
```

i want to know that why this saved in INTERNAL? my file actually is on SD Card! i cant understand why!

Comment: Do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in your app manifest?

Comment: What is the type and value of outPath? What is type and value of values? You are saving in Android settings? What should that be?

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam: yes i have that permision

Comment: @greenapps: its is a file inside my sd card. file path is correct  and code works but saves in INTERNAL settings

Comment: Save in INTERNAL settings? What is saved then? What you got there is only a media store index. Why do you care? And why so reluctant providing full path?

Answer (score 0):

If your file path does not begin with the same value which is returned from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`, then the mode will default to `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Make sure your `outPath` starts with the appropriate path.

Source [MediaStore.Audio.Media]:

```
public static Uri getContentUriForPath(String path) {
    return (path.startsWith(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()) ?
            EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI : INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
}
```